# VBA IF ElseIF Else

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word

Having a problem with If, ElseIf, Else function in VBA.

My code needs to look for "Text1", elseIf needs to look for "Text2", else make a note in a log file.

The problem is I can't seem to change the Find parameters as part of the ElseIF..

```
ElseIf Selection.Find.ClearFormatting    
With Selection.Find
  .Forward = False
  .Text = "Text2"
End With                                            
Selection.Find.Execute Then
```

The ElseIF will only work if I put it infront of The execute line, this means im still searching "Text1" that doesn't exist.

```
ElseIf Selection.Find.Execute Then
```

Any idea where im going wrong?

Full code:

```
Sub Testing()

    Dim LogFile As String

    LogFile = "G:\ErrorLog.txt"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Forward = False
        .Text = "Text1"
    End With

    If Selection.Find.Execute Then

        MsgBox "Found Text1"

        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Forward = False
            .Text = "Text2"
        End With

    ElseIf Selection.Find.Execute Then

         MsgBox "Found Text2"

    Else

        Open LogFile For Append As #1
        Print #1, Now & " " & "Text Field Error" & ": "
        Close #1

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
**If Selection.Find.Execute Then**
       MsgBox "Found Text1"

       Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
       With Selection.Find
           .Forward = False
           .Text = "Text2"
       End With

 **ElseIf Selection.Find.Execute Then**
```

Look the **... These are looking for same. How can it popup an value by same? At least it only can found text 1 or else, but not `ElseIf`.
So you should delete `ElseIf` become `If` only.